# Where - In Clause in OLAP Cube

Tags: mysql, select, olap, cube, olap-cube

I'm using OLAP cube and I want to select data from our MySQL database. What I want is to use "Where-In" clause, as in MySQL:

```
SELECT Id, CompanyName, City, Country
FROM Supplier
WHERE Country IN ('USA', 'UK', 'Japan')
```

As far as I understand, in OLAP cube we select data by "slicing" data. So I think we could NOT achieve st similar to "Where In" clause as above. Can sb has answer or confirmation for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MDX a [WHERE](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Where%20Clause.php) clause is setting one or more hierarchy members (aka. slicing); filtering is rather achieved using [subqueries](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/SubQueries.php) (i.e., SELECT ... (FROM SELECT ... )).

In your example, you could select all the countries and then use a subquery to filter only USA/UK/Japan. Or you could select them directly:

```
SELECT 
   { Id, CompanyName, City, Country } ON 0,
   { [Geo].[USA], [Geo].[UK], [Geo].[Japan] } ON 1
FROM ...
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't understand this part "Or you could select them directly". Could you explain more detailed?

Comment: Done, check the SELECT that should gives you the idea.